# Change default namespace of subelement in lxml

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces

I want to generate this xml with `lxml`:

```
<aroot xmlns="http://a/">
  <broot xmlns="http://b/" xmlns:a="http://a/">
    <child1/>
    <child2/>
    <a:smalltag1/>
    <a:smalltag2/>
  </broot>
</aroot>
```

But the following code (that seems to be correct for this output), does not generates above xml.

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

NS_A = 'http://a/'
NS_B = 'http://b/'

A = ElementMaker(namespace=NS_A, nsmap={None: NS_A, 'b': NS_B})
B = ElementMaker(namespace=NS_B, nsmap={None: NS_B, 'a': NS_A})

elem = A.aroot(
    B.broot(
        B.child1,
        B.child2,
        A.smalltag1,
        A.smalltag2,
    ),
)

print(etree.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True).decode('ascii'))
```

This generates:

```
<aroot xmlns:b="http://b/" xmlns="http://a/">
  <b:broot>
    <b:child1/>
    <b:child2/>
    <smalltag1/>
    <smalltag1/>
  </b:broot>
</aroot>
```

This is a valid xml, but I cannot change the default namespace on subelemnt `broot`.

If I change the `A` `ElementMaker` as following:

```
A = ElementMaker(namespace=NS_A, nsmap={None: NS_A})
```

The output becomes:

```
<aroot xmlns="http://a/">
  <broot xmlns="http://b/">
    <child1/>
    <child2/>
    <smalltag1/>
    <smalltag2/>
  </broot>
</aroot>
```

which is an invalid xml (namespace of `smalltag1` is now b)

and if I change both `A` and `B` as follows:

```
A = ElementMaker(namespace=NS_A, nsmap={None: NS_A})
B = ElementMaker(namespace=NS_B, nsmap={None: NS_B})
```

the output is:

```
<aroot xmlns="http://a/">
  <broot xmlns="http://b/">
    <child1/>
    <child2/>
    <smalltag1 xmlns="http://a/"/>
    <smalltag2 xmlns="http://a/"/>
  </broot>
</aroot>
```

Which is valid, but not desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Using etree:

```
from lxml import etree

NS_A = 'http://a/'
NS_B = 'http://b/'

aroot = Element('{%s}aroot' % (NS_A), nsmap={None: NS_A})
broot = etree.SubElement(aroot, '{%s}broot' % (NS_B), nsmap={None: NS_B, 'a': NS_A})
etree.SubElement(broot, '{%s}child1' % (NS_B))
etree.SubElement(broot, '{%s}child2' % (NS_B))
etree.SubElement(broot, '{%s}smalltag1' % (NS_A))
etree.SubElement(broot, '{%s}smalltag2' % (NS_A))

print etree.tostring(aroot, pretty_print=True)
```

You get:

```
<aroot xmlns="http://a/">
  <broot xmlns:a="http://a/" xmlns="http://b/">
    <child1/>
    <child2/>
    <a:smalltag1/>
    <a:smalltag2/>
  </broot>
</aroot>
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and question code? Only not using the `ElementMaker` interface and using pure lxml?